# How to check if a bind event was called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bind event in JQuery like this :

```
$j("#chart").bind('jqplotDataClick', 
    function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) 
    {

    });
```

In another function adjustLine(),I want to check if the above bind event has been called already or not. Do you know how to do it? Thanks!

```
function adjustLine()
{
    // if the jqplotDataClick event is called, do following

    //else
}
```

Comment: Add a variable to your eventListener and check that.

Comment: You'd have better to explain why you would need that?!

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, it does sound a little like an XY problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a global variable as flag and do the stuff,

```
var flag=false;
$j("#chart").bind('jqplotDataClick', 
    function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) 
    {
        flag=true;
    });

function adjustLine()
{
    // if the jqplotDataClick event is called, do following
    if(flag)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: no, _don't_ use a global variable, use one bound inside a closure.

Comment: @Alnitak thank you for the information. does this approach have any problem?

Comment: You should try to limit your use of global variables to the absolute minimum. This is standard programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [data API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store a flag value

```
$j("#chart").bind('jqplotDataClick', function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex,
data) {
    j$(this).data('jqplotDataClicked', true);
})


function adjustLine() {
    if (j$('#chart').data('jqplotDataClicked')) {
        //clicked
    } else {
        //not
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to only have the handler called once, you can use `.one()` instead of `.bind()` and the handler will be automatically unbound after one use.

Answer (score 0):

First unbind any previously bound event. This will not let you rebind same event to a selector.

```
$('#myButton').unbind('click', onButtonClicked) //remove handler
              .bind('click', onButtonClicked);  //add handler
```